# R- Equation with additional condition. Vector condition

Tags: r, analytics, hierarchical

I've got a problem with computing some expression like this:

[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxvwF.jpg)

I tried use solve function but it shows me matrix must be n x n size.
If someone encountered similar problem please help me or give some sources ;)

Comment: This looks like maths homework. I would solve it with a pencil and a sheet of paper.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to properly implement this and develop . On paper it's simple if we've got small number of factors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While this is in SAS, you should be able to adapt the concept. When trying to solve the equation, I receive the error:

```
proc model;
    endo w1 w2 w3;

    w1 + 2*w2 + 8*w3 = 3.9167*w1;
    (1/2)*w1 + w2 + (1/4)*w3 = 3.9167*w2;
    (1/8)*w1 + 4*w2 + w3 = 3.9167*w3;
    w1 + w2 + w3 = 1;

    solve;
quit;
```

> ERROR: The system of equations cannot be solved because it contains
>   one or more overdetermined components with more equations, 4, than
>   solve variables, 3.

Which is expected, because we have 4 equations and 3 unknowns. One of the equations is redundant.

Instead, let's consider this a system of three equations with a constraint, thus turning it into an optimization/simulation problem. We want to find `w1`, `w2`, `w3` such that all equations are satisfied, with a *constraint* that `w1 + w2 + w3 = 1`.

```
proc model;
    endo w1 w2 w3;

    w1 + 2*w2 + 8*w3 = 3.9167*w1;
    (1/2)*w1 + w2 + (1/4)*w3 = 3.9167*w2;
    (1/8)*w1 + 4*w2 + w3 = 3.9167*w3;

    restrict w1 + w2 + w3 = 1;

    solve / optimize printall;
quit;
```

[image: Solution]
[image: Details]